# How to call overload method from a function and pass different argument types in c#

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I have two overloaded methods as below:

```
Render(PDFTable table)
Render(PDFText text)
```

I have to call these methods from another method inside a for..each loop and pass the parameters as below:

```
foreach (var item in sectionPDF.sectionElements)
{
    if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(PDFTable)))
    {
        Render((PDFTable)item);
    }
    else if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(PDFText)))
    {
        Render((PDFText)item);
    }
}
```

I would like to know, if there is any way to remove the if..else statements and dynamically resolve the type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could move the if inside Render, and use `if (typeof(item) == typeof(PDFTable))`

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. C# doesn't support virtual dispatch based on argument type. Overload resolution is a purely compile-time matter. Hence you have to make the decision yourself, either the way you are doing it now, by using some form of a decision table, using a provider class that makes the decision, whatever else fits your software design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic`.
First declare a method like this:

```
void RenderDispatch(dynamic item)
{
    Render(item);
}

Render((PDFTable)
Render((PDFText)
```

Then in the `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in sectionPDF.sectionElements)
{
    RenderDispatch(item);
}
```

The runtime take care to call the correct override.

**Beware** that `dynamic` incurs in performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your "Render" method generic:

```
void Render<T> (T item)
{
    //your stuff here
}
```

then:

```
foreach (var item in sectionPDF.sectionElements)
{
    Render(item);
}
```